# Show error or success from controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sweetalert2

I am using sweetAlert to show popUp message and i want to know if there's any why to show this alert from the controller

**myPage.html**

```
<form th:object="${ecran}"  th:action="@{/createIssue}"  method="post"  >
 ...

<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" >Valider la demande</a>
</form>
```

**My Alert**

```
swal("Are you sure you want to do this?", {
buttons: ["Oh noez!", true],
});
```

**myController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/createIssue")
public String creerUneDemande(@Valid @ModelAttribute("ecran") Ecran ecran, BindingResult result,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same by setting a flag in controller using modal attribute and based on the flag value you can show the alert in view page.

```
@PostMapping("/createIssue")
public String creerUneDemande(@Valid @ModelAttribute("ecran") Ecran ecran, BindingResult result,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

...
//if everything working fine then set the flag value
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flag","showAlert");
}
```

In the view page accept the value of the flag inside javascript code and execute the condition something like below.

```
if('${flag}' == 'showAlert'){
 swal("Are you sure you want to do this?", {
 buttons: ["Oh noez!", true],
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer i've done it with the addFlashAttribute your answer is good but need some clearification (in the view)

Comment: yeah it's the answer that i talk about

Comment: Glad to help you.